# Use snake case ABP + Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, abp

I'm using abp with PostgreSQL.

When executing the migrator, the names of tables and columns are being created with double quotation marks, e.g. `"AbpUsers"`.

When using the name of tables and columns in this way, without space and with upper and lower case letters, Postgres automatically adds double quotes.

So I would like to use snake case: abp_user instead of "AbpUser". Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try renaming the table as below

```
migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "OldTableName", schema: "dbo", newName: "NewTableName", newSchema: "dbo");
```

[image]